# How do i pass in Interface objects as parameter Class[] interFaces In Proxy.NewProxyInstance?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to set onTreePreferenceClickListener with Reflection in PreferenceManager Class.

```
public  static void SetOnPreferenceTreeClickListener (PreferenceManager manager, IOnPreferenceTreeClickListener listener)
    {
        try {

            Class cl = Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof(PreferenceManager));
            Field onPreferenceTreeClickListener = cl.GetDeclaredField ("mOnPreferenceTreeClickListener");
            onPreferenceTreeClickListener.Accessible = true;
            if (listener != null) {
                Java.Lang.Object proxy = Proxy.NewProxyInstance (manager.Class.ClassLoader, new Class[] {Class.FromType(typeof(IOnPreferenceTreeClickListener)) }, new MyInvocationHandler (listener));
                onPreferenceTreeClickListener.Set (manager, proxy);
            } else {
                onPreferenceTreeClickListener.Set (manager, null);
            }
        } catch (System.Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine (TAG + " Couldn't set PreferenceManager.mOnPreferenceTreeClickListener by reflection " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the class object from  listener.GetType().

But it throws exception either that it isnt a derived from java or IllegalArgument.